# Look for name in a list in a dataframe within a list

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop

I created a list of names and a list of dataframes

```
i <- 1
mylist <- c()
list.dfs <- list(d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9)

while (i<37) {
  a <- paste("ABCD", i, sep = "")
  mylist <- c(mylist, a)
  }
  i <- i+1
}
```

These variables in mylist (ABCD1, ABCD2, ...) are all part of the dataframes d0:d9. Now I want to change these variables in the dataframes in a loop.

```
for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
   list.dfs[[i]]$mylist[[i]] <- as.numeric(list.dfs[[i]]$mylist[[i]])
}
```

It says "Unknown or uninitialised column: `mylist`.".

However, when I run the following code, it gives me the correct names:

```
for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
 print(mylist[[i]])
}
```

Comment: You can't use `$` for a dynamic object.

Comment: So you mean for the $mylist[[i]] command? How should I solve it then? Thanks a lot

Comment: I guess so. I can't help you since your issue is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why the `while` loop if `paste0("ABCD", 1:37)` does the same?

Comment: It was just for creating the list of the names. But you are right about the other option. Can I just it for the loop then?